# Settling time vs Bandwidth of Digipot

Tags: digital-potentiometer

I am considering to use digipot for designing programmable gain amplifier.

I will have to amplify 1MHz sine wave signal.

Looking at the datasheet of [AD5243](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/609/AD5243_5248-586756.pdf), I came across two parameters.

1. Bandwidth = 4.8MHz
2. Vw Settling Time = 1us

What does Settling time refer to? Does it mean that the settling time when I change the position of the potentiometer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bandwidth and settling time are not directly related. Settling time is most easily seen with a DC signal. See [the data sheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/609/AD5243_5248-586756.pdf) Figure 29. After a step command is issued, the output will settle to 1 lsb of final value in 1 usec or less.

Comment: So, If I keep the step same, i won't have to worry about settling time? And AC signal will only be affected by bandwidth?

Comment: You do have to worry about settling time, but it's not the same as bandwidth. And the AC signal will be significantly affected during settling time.